# Extract ways and corresponding nodes from .json file of OSM and save to CSV

Tags: openstreetmap, json

I fetched the highways data from turbo overpass API, and save the result in json file. OSM json has very nested document structure. I want to get the ways and their corresponding node IDs from json file into separate csv file such that each node have corresponding way IDs in it. How can i perform this?

Comment: You can obtain CSV output from Overpass API directly. However you will need an `foreach` statement to print all nodes for each way. See https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/45212/how-to-get-ways-and-associated-nodes-in-csv-with-overpass-ql/45213 as an example.

Comment: i have used that script before, but it was giving just the the lat and long and road names. I want the numeric Ways IDs and their underlying list of nodes in separate columns is there any other way of doing that from json response of turbo over pas API?